# How to switch (on/off) the behavior while the checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys. I have a problem that i can't resolve. I need to switch the behavior using ".on/.off" methods that will be working when i set or remove the tick from the checkbox. How can i do that?

For example: I have a button that will be zooming in/change color/moving by pressing on it. But when i set the tick on one of a checkboxes, i need to disable this event from the button using ".off" method.

I tried like

```
$(".button").on('click', function(){           
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(".button2").on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active2');
});

$(".button3").on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active3');
});

$(".button4").on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active4');
});

var check = $("#check");
check.change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
      $('.button').off('click');
  }




});
```

but for some reason it will disable my event until i refresh the page, even if i remove the tick from one of my checkboxes

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you are just disabling the first button? Can you confirm?

Comment: @Nope Well, I don't turn off the button, I turn off the event. The problem is that the event is in a disabled state until I refresh the page. But I need to disable the event using ".off" method if the checkbox is checked and enable it if the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you tick the checkbox, your code will remove the click listener from the `.button` element and you're not setting it back when the checkbox is unchecked.

So, if you want the click listener on the `.button` element to fire again when the checkbox is unchecked, you can do any one of the two things as mentioned below.

First, you can add an `else` block after the `if` block in the `change` listener of checkbox. Following code will work for this approach:

```
var check = $("#check");
check.change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        // This will remove the click listener from the button if checkbox is checked
        $('.button').off('click');
    } 
    else {
         // This will again add the click listener to the button if checkbox is not checked
         $(".button").on('click', function(){ 
             $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
         });
    }
});
```

But I will not recommend the above approach because it will unnecessarily increase the size of code.

Here's the second and a better approach. Inside the click event handler function, you can add an `if` statement to check if the checkbox is ticked. Below is the code for the same:

```
$(".button").on('click', function(){ 
    if (! $("#check").is(':checked')) { 
        // This will only be fired if checkbox is not checked
        $(this).toggleClass('active')
    }
});
```

You can add this if to any other block according to your requirement.

The main advantages of using the above code are:

1. Code will not be increased as compared to 1st approach
2. You don't need a `change` listener for the checkbox (Yeah! Just remove it!)